# Open Flutter web in dart server

Tags: flutter, dart, server

I am building a dart server and I want to return a flutter web app. Therefore I used **webbev build**. For each request my server is responding which the webbev file build/index.html. Sadly, I just see a white page. Is there a way to fix that?
The source code looks like the following:

```
import 'dart:io';
File targetFile = File('build/index.html');
Future<void> main() async {
  print('starts launching the server');
  final address = InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4;
  final port = 9999;
  final server = await HttpServer.bind(address, port);
  print(
      'Server started listening on: http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
await for( HttpRequest req in server){
  req.response
  ..headers.contentType = ContentType.html;
  try{
    await req.response.addStream(targetFile.openRead());
  }catch(e){}
  await req.response.close();
  

  }
}
```

Comment: Your server has to be prepared to respond with the other site files as they're requested. A flutter web app consists of more than just a single HTML file.

Comment: That's true, they are all in the build directory, but how can I prepare my server?

Comment: Use the requested URI to determine the path of the `File` to return.